# Android/JDBC:JTDS and Sybase

Tags: android, sybase

We are trying to use JTDS with Sybase and Android. We are using the "SQL Anywhere" formerly Sybase Anywhere (we think???), and it seems as if we are talking to Sybase (Sybase 9), because the exception is "Login Failure" and we are using a connection string such as:

```
String conn_str = "jdbc:jtds:sybase://192.168.1.100:2638/dbname";
```

Then calling:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conn_str, "user", "passwd");
```

We keep getting the login failure with a known good user and passwd.

It is *very* difficult to find any information on Android talking to Sybase or any example connections within SourceForge.

How can we fix this problem?

Comment: Please [reconsider your use of JDBC on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853367/jdbc-vs-web-service-for-android).

Comment: I agree with the Web Service vs Direct Connect (Especially if this were a public connection) BUT my task is to connect directly to Sybase without changing the current Sybase environment.

Comment: SQL Anywhere version 9 dates back to 2003 and [end of life in 2010](https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/SQLANY/SAP+SQL+Anywhere+Supported+Platforms+and+Engineering+Support+Status) If the Sybase database logs don't provide any info, the age of that software explains why you won't find anything on the internet.

Comment: I suspect you're right Morrison BUT had to throw one last hail-mary before we abandoned the ship!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Morrison Chang had](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75560768/android-jdbcjtds-and-sybase/76019647#comment133314800_75560768) the right answer as it turned out here!

> SQL Anywhere version 9 dates back to 2003 and end of life in 2010. If the Sybase database logs don't provide any info, the age of that software explains why you won't find anything on the Internet.